# back button is faster than calling finish() in onOptionItemSelected menu

Tags: android, performance

I have a simple activity with an image view and a simple menuItem which is used for came back in the previus activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I just realized that if I press the back button for coming back in the previous activity, android do it really fast, but pressing the menu item above, it waste a second. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way of doing a return back is

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

By calling `finish()` you schedule the current activity for *destruction*, i.e. to call `onDestroy()`. This does some clean-up and thus produces an overhead and you experience therewith some latency. So, if you don't really have to use `finish()` there (e.g. to close some dialogs or cursors), just omit it and use the provided default solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try.. this doesn't come back in the previus activity! just nothing happens, I post my code..  the activity is open from a normal intent..  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            case R.id.share_image:
                //TODO
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Comment: You have to provide the logical parent of your activity in the manifest file. The attribute for that is `android:parentActivityName`.